# Automatically managing license/author/version header in source files

Tags: version-control, licensing

It is generally considered good practice to add some lines with author, version and license information to the top of source files. For instance, Gnu GPL v3 suggests to add

```
<one line to give the program's name and a brief idea of what it does.>
Copyright (C) <year>  <name of author>

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms [SNIP]
```

I find it tedious to add it manually to each file, and to have to update them all every now and then when some of this information changes (new authors, copyright years, version bumps).

Is there a way to manage this automatically, so that I only have to edit this stuff in one place and it gets automagically copied around?

If needed, you may assume that I am using any modern revision control system.

Comment: Please clarify, which VCS and under which OS you want to use. Also - do you have (plan to use) any CI|Deploy tools?

Comment: Side note - year of copyright protection isn't year per se, it's (*dynamic*) range in form start-end (according to FSF suggestions and pure plain logic)

Comment: @LazyBadger: I use mainly Linux+git, but I am also curious about solutions for other systems. And let's say no CI/Deploy, but I do not see how this could be relevant, since they only work at a later stage (I want the copyright lines to be there in the VCS, *before*  I deploy). Regarding the copyright year, no matter if the format is 2007-2011 or 2011 only, I still have to update it every year, right?

Comment: Federico - for Git-related solution you have to wait git-boys (because they painstakingly pursue and downvote my ideas and solutions, feel free to use search or my history). Using deploys-tools **IS relevant**, because it allows you to have some type of pre-processing tools, not related directly to used SCM. For (c) range - I do not maintain it by hand, it expanded automagically after first commit in year... But I don't use Git

Comment: And yes, I add header-part in sources only on deploy|publishing sources stage, in strictly personal repo it's wasted time and resources (SVN and HG)

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to host the code online on a Bitbucket public repo, so for me it is imperative that the copyright lines are already there in the SCM. I am interested in the method that you use for "(c) range - I do not maintain it by hand, it expanded automagically after first commit in year". Could you please describe it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> It is generally considered good practice to add some lines with author, version and license information to the top of source files.

That depends. First of all there are two (and more) ways to do this:

- manage licensing information per file
- manage licensing information in a central location

If you start a project from scratch, the per-file method is often easy to do while keeping things clear. As you write, over time it becomes more difficult to keep track of things. So more and more projects switch to the central location variant.

The file-by-file method has the benefit that the scope of a work is clear. Often you write the name of the application in the file-comment. If a single file is taken out for some reason, the information is still in there and the documentation chain is not broken.

With the central location method, the benefit is that this is normally supported by your version control software, for example GIT. Commits can be signed by the committing person, and author can be given. It's documented who has written which code automatically and that information is stored in a central location: the VCS.

Keep a COPYING file with your package where you provide the main information centrally. You can easily generate the list of authors via the VCS. And per each file you can create one header that just specifies which software and where to look into, just a bare outline:

```
/**
 * Flux Deluxe v3.2.0 - Vector Drawing Redefined
 *
 * Copyright 2010, 2012 by its authors. 
 * Some rights reserved. See COPYING, AUTHORS.
 */
```

If you release a new version in a new year it's a no-brainer to update all files.

Comment: Well my question is exactly how you manage this "no-brainer" of updating all files, without, of course, doing it by hand. Is there any tool around for that? Do you write your own regexp for every version change and hope it doesn't match too much? Do you edit each file by hand?

Comment: To replace text in (multiple) files you can use [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html). Additionally depending on which IDE you use there is also search and replace in files quite often. That's what I meant with "no-brainer": Multi-File-Search-And-Replace. If the headers stay the same (at least the main part of it), it's just a straight forward search and replace.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was not satisfied with this solution because there's always the risk that it matches too much (replace all "Flux Deluxe v.3.2.0" with v.3.2.1? Your CHANGELOG file and your compatibility error messages may have something against that...), so I asked if there is any tool especially written for that around. I'll accept "no, we all roll our own regexp" as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the [License Header Manager](https://github.com/rubicon-oss/LicenseHeaderManager.git)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems a good solution for Visual Studio users.

Answer (score 0):

If working with Visual Studio, you could use macro's and attach a shortcut to it.
Then, when creating a new file, use the shortcut to add a header.
If you want to be sure that a header has been included in each file, you can use StyleCop.

Following links might be helpful:
http://abhijitjana.net/2010/12/05/add-document-header-for-files-automatically-in-visual-studio/
http://stylecop.codeplex.com/

In Eclipse, there is also macro support so you should be able to do the same as suggested for VS. However, I do not have any experience with that.

For Java, there is an alternative to StyleCop:
http://stylecop.codeplex.com/

I haven't heard of any SVN-tools that adapt the files itself.
Using macro's in your editor is the closest thing to what you want.

Comment: Macros work for creating the header the first time (as well as copy-and-paste), but not for updating it, unless I am missing something. And they still require a quantity of work that scales as O(n) with the number of files rather than O(1).